# I don't know how to use 'fill=?'

Tags: tex-core

It's the first time I write tex profiles,I want to know how to use the style{ fill=}.

Comment: You mean `\fill`?

Comment: You might be using TikZ... in that case, read the TikZ manual first.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to `tikz`, then here is a very simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red!50, thick]  (1,2) rectangle (3,5);
\filldraw[color=blue!60, fill=orange!50, very thick](-1,0) circle (1.5);
\filldraw[color=blue!60, fill=cyan!50, very thick](5,0) circle (1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

For more please see the manual and overleaf website.

Comment: Thank you very much